# How to set arg using gdbinit but just when a specific binary is loaded in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, elf, gdbinit

How to `set arg -d` through the file ~/.gdbinit but just when a specific binary is loaded in gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with python you can add something like the following to your gdbinit

```
py
def on_bin_echo(): gdb.execute("set arg -d")
exec_funcs = {"/bin/echo" : on_bin_echo}
map(lambda x: exec_funcs[x.filename]() if exec_funcs.has_key(x.filename) else None, gdb.objfiles())
end
```